# Pass input element's text to button's click handler

Tags: javascript, onclick

```
<script>
  var addSubReddit = function(topicName){
    console.log(topicName)
    //add it to the list of existing subreddit topics
  }
</script>
<form>
   <input placeholder='Create new subreddit' value=''>
   <button type='submit' onclick="addSubReddit(....)">Create</button>
</form>
```

How to access the input element's text value and pass it as a string value to button's onclick function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need it to pass as parameter to `function`. You can get that in function

Html:

```
<input id="myText" placeholder='Create new subreddit' value=''>
<button type='submit' onclick="addSubReddit()">Create</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function addSubReddit() {
    var textValue = document.getElementById('#myText').value;
    ....
    ....
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
<script>
 function buttonFunction(){
var name = document.getElementById("nameId").value;
alert("entered input is "+name);
}
</script>
<form>
   <input placeholder='Create new subreddit' value='' id="nameId" name="nameId">
   <button type='submit' onclick="buttonFunction()">Create</button>
</form>
```

Comment: `var name = getElementById("nameId").value;` needs to be changed as `var name = document.getElementById("nameId").value;`